# How to map in Graduated style in QGIS when it does not show the option to?

Tags: qgis, style

I am trying to map a column through Graduated style in QGIS. But the values in my column have a few repeated values of example 1000s, 1003s, 1005s etc. and the program recognizes it as categorized style. If I map it as categorized I will have over 1400 categories. What can I do to plot as a Graduated style? It is not appearing in the drop down option.

Comment: Is your field string type? I would suggest to create a new field and store it as numeric or double precision. You can use it with graduated style

Answer (score 1):

check your field properties, it might be numbers stored as characters, hence qgis will not recognize them as "graduable" ; it also happens when you have a joined field from a dragged-and-dropped csv

Comment: I did do a join and the type is Qstring, type name is String. anyway that I can change that?

Comment: I guess you imported them from a csv, that's the default, to be imported as qstring; i recommend to make a dbf, that way they'll be imported as numeric (check the field type first); libreoffice calc reads and writes dbf's (excel doesn't)